# Are object getters been automatically called when output object in console?

Tags: javascript

Previously I thought that object's getter will be computed if and only if will be explicitly called:

```js
const obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get latest() {
    console.log("checkpoint1")
    if (this.log.length === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
};

console.log(obj.latest); // called!
```

However if we try to print the `obj` in console

```
console.log(obj)
```

`checkpoint1` from 4th row will also printed! But I noticed this phenomena when run some UI tests without explicit calling of getters, so the printing of object in console on not only one case when getters could be implicitly called.

By why getter has been called?

Comment: Which `console` (in which environment) are you using? There are different things they do, for example it doesn't print `checkpoint1` in browsers.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the comment. I am using browser console. Just checked output in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t7dj6un/) - I have `checkpoint1`.

Comment: @Bergi Checked on NodeJS. I had `checkpoint1` in NodeJS output too.

Comment: That's not the browser console, that's the (horrible) jsfiddle console. Try executing the code right from the devtools console, and see an interactive object displayed :-)

Comment: Node.js uses `util.inspect`, which accesses all properties of an object (and thereby invokes their getters) in order to return a string representation of the object.

Comment: Accessing an object's property will call the getter function(if it is a getter), That's how getter and setter works. The purpose of getter and setter is to get/set object property value dynamically(do some logic behind the scene) and return the value as any other property instead of invoking as `function`. [Read in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)